# ¿Cómo obtener la ip del cliente usando nestjs?

Tags: nodejs, typescript, backend, ip, nestjs

Estoy usando `nestjs` en mi backend y necesito obtener la IP del cliente que hace una petición (puede ser un *post*, un *get* etc.) para luego usarla en un servicio. Busqué información en *Google* pero no pude implementar las opciones que me daban ahí. No adjunto código pues no tengo ni idea de que implementar pues recién empecé a trabajar con `nestjs`.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la ip del cliente, simplemente usa el decorador `@Ip` del paquete `@nestjs/common`. Un ejemplo muy simple quedaría:

```
import { Controller, Get, Ip, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(AppController.name);

  @Get()
  getIp(@Ip() ip): string {
    this.logger.log(`The client ip is ${ip}.`);
    return ip;
  }
}
```

La ip que recibes en la petición, puedes pasarla luego al servicio que desees implementar muy fácilmente. Si llamas el servicio desde la consola:

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000
::ffff:127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya había implementado esta solución y la respuesta que me da es 127.0.0.1, desearía saber cómo puedo hacer que me dé otra dirección para probar que esté bien mi código y que no me de una IP que no es la real

Comment: @YasmanyDelgado revisa la ip de tu pc, y en el navegador del movil, escribe `http://<IP del PC>:3000` (suponiendo que lo tengas en la misma red). Deberías obtener la ip local de tu movil.